# MySQL > Compare and Report Time differences from certain rows only

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a new report and I'm having trouble figuring out the logic.  I have a table similar to the following:

[image: ost_thread_entry osTicket table]

M=Message (There is only one per thread)
R=Response (There can be any number of responses)
N=Note (Not needed for the report and can be excluded via additional WHERE statement).
For each thread_id get the time for the type=M column and then the get FIRST type=R time, compare those two times and report such as

```css
.thread_col {
  width: 80px;
}

.report_col {
  width: 200px;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class='thread_col'>Thread</th>
    <th class='report_col'>Time to First Response</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>124 Minutes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>18 Minutes</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>22 Minutes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried some things but my MySQL is a little rusty. I assume we'll need sub-queries in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sound like a self-join to me:

```
SELECT t.*, MIN(t1.created) 
FROM t 
LEFT JOIN t as t1 ON t1.thread_id = t.thread_id AND t1.type = 'R' 
WHERE t.type = 'M' 
GROUP BY t.thread_id
```

You select all types M from the table, then join the lowest response time to it.
Must be a LEFT JOIN, because not all messages actually have a response. And you need the group, because they could have more than one response.

You then have the two times and can calculate the difference in minutes in PHP for the output.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's exactly what I needed!